# Google Sheets: using Query in ArraryFormula

Tags: filter, lambda, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas

I have a sheet to apply Query function to get the respective search data row by row. But I need to apply ArrayFormula to automate this search process. I want to know how should I do.

**Expected Result**

Check phrase    Result 1    Result 2    Result 3    Result 4
Apple   Apple   Ice Apple   Custard apple/Sugar apple/Sweetsop  Rose apple/Water apple
berry   Cape gooseberry/Inca berry/Physalis
man Mango   Mangosteen
mom
fruit   Dragon fruit    Egg fruit   Passion fruit   Black sapote/Chocolate pudding fruit
j   Jackfruit   Jujube  Jenipapo
nake    Snake fruit/Salak
me  Horned Melon    Honeydew melon  Medlar fruit    Mouse melon

**Currently**

Check phrase    Result 1    Result 2    Result 3    Result 4
Apple   Apple   Ice Apple
berry   Apple   Ice Apple
man Apple   Ice Apple
mom Apple   Ice Apple
fruit   Apple   Ice Apple
j   Apple   Ice Apple
nake    Apple   Ice Apple
me  Apple   Ice Apple

What I currently achieve is for single row using this:

`=IF(LEN(F2:F)=0, IFERROR(1/0), IF(LEN(F2:F)>0, Query(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(Fruits!B:B, "select B where B contains '" & F2:F & "'")),"select * limit 12")))`

How should I do. Please advise me. I attach my file link here.
[My Google Sheet file]
(https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QDfruKtwJjmRQWqTlO3sBM-e9vp9QKwmla23ss0U1sY/edit#gid=1411907513)

Comment: could you format you Expected Result? it is current difficult to understand you question. Explain a little bit more about what you are trying to achieve will even be better.

Comment: to me, it seems like you are trying to extract every match of the data in Current!F:F from source Fruits!B:B, and output the result into columns?

Comment: Yes. Later I will reformat the table. FTB please see attached file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(LAMBDA(a, b, BYROW(a, LAMBDA(x, 
 TRANSPOSE(IFNA(FILTER(b, SEARCH(IF(x="", "×", x), b)))))))
 (F2:INDEX(F:F, MAX(ROW(F:F)*(F:F<>""))), Fruits!B2:B), 9^9, 12)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: result]

```
=LAMBDA(PHRASES,FRUITS,
 BYROW(PHRASES,LAMBDA(FRUIT,
  TRANSPOSE(FILTER(FRUITS,REGEXMATCH(FRUITS,FRUIT)))
 ))
)(QUERY({Current!F2:F},"WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL"),QUERY({Fruits!B:B},"WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL"))
```

Put this formula into G2, the result should be same as this image.

What we are doing here is...

1. use QUERY to get rid of blanks in range Current!F2:F, name the array as PHRASES with LAMBDA.
2. use QUERY to get rid of blanks in range Fruits!B:B, name the array as FRUITS with LAMBDA.
3. use BYROW to work on the single column array FRUITS value by value, with...
4. LAMBDA inside BYROW to name the value of each ROW as FRUIT,
5. use FILTER to filter the array FRUITS,
6. use REGEXMATCH to set the condition of the filter funciton in step.5, which returns TRUE for string matches,
7. TRANSPOSE the result of each filter to met your display format.

The filter can also be replaced by another QUERY function if you want, outputs should be identical in this case.

```
=LAMBDA(PHRASES,FRUITS,
 BYROW(PHRASES,LAMBDA(FRUIT,
  TRANSPOSE(QUERY(FRUITS,"WHERE Col1 CONTAINS '"&FRUIT&"'"))
 ))
)(QUERY({Current!F2:F},"WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL"),QUERY({Fruits!B:B},"WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL"))
```

According to you request in comments, this is the updated code:

1. to make it case insensitive, apply UPPER() to Col1 and FRUIT inside the transposed query,
2. to show blank instead of #N/A when there is no output on that row, apply IFNA() to the whole QUERY() inside the TRANSPOSE(),
3. to limit the length of the output array, warp up the TRANSPOSE() with ARRAY_CONSTRAIN().

```
=LAMBDA(NOTNULL,LAMBDA(PHRASES,FRUITS,
 BYROW(PHRASES,LAMBDA(PHRASE,
  ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
   TRANSPOSE(IFNA(
    QUERY(FRUITS,"WHERE UPPER(Col1) CONTAINS '"&UPPER(PHRASE)&"'"),
   "")),
  1,12)
 ))
)(QUERY({Current!F2:F},NOTNULL),QUERY({Fruits!B:B},NOTNULL)))("WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL")
```

[image: image2]

The code will leave an empty row if there is no match found, which is required in your comment `* Show blank if no valid return. (instead of #N/A)`,

What do you means `When there is no phrase match, that row skipped`?

It won't in my test environment.

But if you mean when you leave some part of the 'check phrase' column empty, it does break the calculation, because this case is never mentioned, that you may have blanks in the check phrase column, so I simply didn't handle it.

And if that is the case, you should always include such conditions into the sample data you provide at the very begining, otherwise this is another issue, and maybe better to open another question to ask about a solution after you trying to work it out on your own.

Anyway, this is a quick solution if you need to handle blanks in Check phrase column:

```
=LAMBDA(NOTNULL,LAMBDA(PHRASES,FRUITS,
 BYROW(PHRASES,LAMBDA(PHRASE,
  ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IF(PHRASE="","",QUERY(FRUITS,"WHERE UPPER(Col1) CONTAINS '"&UPPER(PHRASE)&"'")),"")),1,12)
 ))
)({Current!F2:F},QUERY({Fruits!B:B},NOTNULL)))("WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL")
```

The reason why the output result shifts upward when there are blanks in 'Check phrase' column, is because, as I said, I uses QUERY to get rid of extra blanks of the 2 source data, this helps speed things up a bit, but if there are blanks between array values, they will also be removed, which lead to the reference array being shortened.

To handle this issue, the easiest slove is, instead of removing the blanks, leave them there, and inside IFNA(), wherever encountering empty PHRASE, use a IF() to skip it by doing nothing, which result in leaving a blank row.

Comment: BYROW() take an array as reference, and proceed the values row by row, which means it feed the function inside it with only one row of values a time, in our case, since it is a one-column-dataset, BYROW() will be feeding the phrases in 'Check phrase' column each-by-each to the funciton inside it, THIS FED DATA SET IS ALWAYS ONE SINGLE ROW.

Comment: The reason we are using BYROW() is because, like SUM(), some function cannot use ArrayFormula() to reference a range of data and return result row by row or col by col.

Comment: QUERY() and FILTER() are one of those funcitons that doesn't work well with ArrayFormula()

Comment: I got it. Thanks Ping. You save my days!

Comment: Hi Ping, please check again. When there is no phrase match, that row skipped.

Comment: it leaves an empty row when there is no match as you have requested, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found this post looking for a solution to my problem, I have came up with below that seems simpler than previous approaches:

```
=BYROW(F2:F,LAMBDA(phrase,if(phrase<>"",IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(query(Fruits!B2:B4944,"select B where B contains '"&phrase&"' ")),),)))
```

Hope it might help someone in the future.